# Gadgets will not equip/unequip

Tags: jetpack-joyride

After the most recent update I can no longer equip or unequip gadgets. I am stuck with the coin magnet and lucky last.

Comment: Welcome Larry!  You're probably better asking Halfbrick support.  https://support.halfbrick.com/hc/en-us  On Arqade, this question is at best, temporary as it only applies to the current version.  Additionally, what device are you on?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem too (on the iOS version). I contacted Halfbrick about it, but they just said

"**Thanks for the email and sorry for the inconvenience.
This is currently an issue our development team are aware of and trying to get resolved as soon as possible. Please check for updates regularly as this will be resolved with an update when it has been made available.**"

So that's what I did. I waited until the next update patch, and the problem was fixed!

(yeah, I know, that probably means the problem has probably already been solved for you as well).